# What should CLASSPATH be set to in order to use NekoHTML in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, classpath, libraries

I have found several snippets that use NekoHTML library in Groovy scripts, e.g.

```
def page = new XmlSlurper(new org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser()).parse('http://groovy.codehaus.org/')
def data = page.depthFirst().grep{ it.name() == 'A' && it.@href.toString().endsWith('.html') }.'@href'
data.each { println it }
```

So I downloaded Groovy, and then I downloaded NekoHTML.

NekoHTML is located here:
`D:\TOOLS\nekohtml-1.9.18\`

When I run the snippet, I get:

```
D:\SCRIPTS\webtesting.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser
 @ line 4, column 27.
   def page = new XmlSlurper(new org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser()).parse('http://groovy.codehaus.or
g/')
```

My research tells me that I need to include NekoHTML in the classpath.

So I set up an environment variable CLASSPATH and it equals:
`CLASSPATH=D:\TOOLS\nekohtml-1.9.18\src`

I opened another cmd window and ran my test groovy script. I get the same error as above.

What should my CLASSPATH be set to refer to NekoHTML components with org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need `nekohtml-1.9.18.jar` and `xercesImpl-2.10.0.jar` on your classpath.

Or you could just add a `@Grab` to the top of your script

```
@Grab( 'net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.18' )
```

And `groovy webtesting.groovy` would fetch these dependencies for you.  Of course, it depends how the script is being run

Comment: @Guys what about ? or how do you use the package found at  source forge .net ? any idea when i extracted it i found a bunch of jars inside it ?

Comment: and Forgotten how to import both class it ?

Comment: oh i mean i on sourceforge.net there is NekoHtmlParser Zip for download ? what can you do with it ?

Comment: @danielad I guess you need to add the jars to the classpath as it [shows here in the documentation](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/usage.html)?